# Why is the list of selected files always empty if I obtain the file list before onchange?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show names of files after I choose them. So, why is the files list empty in the `onchange` handler?

Here is my code:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    let list = document.getElementById("demo");
    let files = document.getElementById("addFileId").files;

    document.getElementById("addFileId").onchange = function () {
        console.log(files);
        console.log(files[0]);

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            let li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerText = files[i].name;
            list.appendChild(li);
        }
    };
};
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple class="form-control"
    name="file" id="addFileId" required>

<ul id="demo"></ul>
```

Comment: Put your`let files =` inside your event, otherwise your asking for the files before you have selected them.

Comment: Actually, that’s not it. The `files` property always refers to the same `FileList`. Selecting files mutates this list, so putting `let files =`…`;` inside the listener makes no difference. @Enesan The code _already_ works fine.

Comment: @SebastianSimon  I get `undefined` selecting a file without moving that line, I'm using Chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: @SebastianSimon  Just tried in Firefox and it keeps the same instance, so it looks like Chrome creates a new instance, so maybe best the OP does what I said and don't assume FileList is always the same instance..

Comment: @Keith Firefox Nightly 100.0a1. Alright, I just checked in Chrome, and there is a difference. I think I know why this incompatibility exists: the [specification](//html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element) neither defines [SameObject] nor [NewObject] for the `files` IDL attribute. It also doesn’t declare it as `readonly`. So it’s underspecified whether `files === document.getElementById("addFileId").files` should be `true` or `false`. Looks like there’s a GitHub issue in the DOM spec to be reported…

Comment: @SebastianSimon  Kudos for checking the spec, nice to know..

Comment: @SebastianSimon, yeah, i just have tried in firefox, it's really working (: 
 thanks for this information

Comment: Digging a bit further, `files` _used_ to be readonly, but there was a [desire to set the `files` property to a different `FileList` instance](//github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1391). The attribute extension [\[SameObject\]](//webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#SameObject) _only_ applies to readonly attributes, and the [\[NewObject\]](//webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#NewObject) extension _only_ applies to methods. So the `files` _getter_ (where a `files` setter also exists) cannot have either attribute extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the file list object is acquired *before* the change event fires.  By the time the event actually happens, information in the list has become stale, while the browser already has attached a new file list to the DOM node.  The solution is to obtain the file list *inside* the event handler:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    let list = document.getElementById("demo");
    let addFileId = document.getElementById("addFileId");
    
    addFileId.onchange = function () {
        let files = addFileId.files;
        console.log(files);
        console.log(files[0]);

        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            let li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerText = files[i].name;
            list.appendChild(li);
        }
    };
};
```

I’ll note, however, that amusingly, the asker’s sample works just fine, unmodified, in Firefox 91 ESR, and commenters describe it acts the same in newer versions as well.  Apparently Firefox, instead of creating a new list, updates the existing file list object.  Chromium behaves like described in the question; I have not tested a WebKit-based browser, but I imagine it acts like the latter.  As of 2022-03-16, the [HTML specification says that upon changing the file selection](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#update-the-file-selection) the browser should

> Update *element*'s selected files so that it represents the user's selection.

which can be interpreted either way.  So it is probably best not to rely on either behaviour.

Comment: `So it is probably best not to rely on either behaviour.`  Not sure what you mean by that, you can of course rely on the behaviour that the list is a new instance or existing.  It's just you can't rely on it been the same instance mutated.

Comment: Oh, the [spec](//html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#dom-input-files) actually says _“On getting [the `files` IDL attribute], it must return a `FileList` object that **represents the current selected files. The same object must be returned until the list of selected files changes.**”_ (emphasis mine). This can still be interpreted either way, but I think changing the reference might have been implied here…